# Predicting future expenses

Tags: calculation, forecasting

I'm trying to develop a tool that predicts my future expenses based on my past expenses.

Example:

I've spent $150, $200, and $180 on fuel during each of the last three months.  Accounting for the rise in price of fuel and my recent expenditures, what will be my expected fuel costs during each of the next three months?

Is there a formula I can use to make this prediction?

Comment: If you spent $480 on fuel over the last three months, it is reasonable to assume that you will spend approximately $480 over the next three months.  It will be close.  Is there a reason that you need to be more precise than that?

Comment: Yes there is! This was just an example. I pretend to use the formula for any expense type (food, bank, etc) in any period (months, years).

Comment: @BenMiller I guess OP wants to factor in the inflation of fuel and budget accordingly. :)

Comment: That's the idea.

Comment: You are looking apply a level of precision that's far finer than the data you are analyzing. By this, I mean your 3 data points have a range of 50, and standard deviation of 25. If gas rises, say 5%, and you add $9 to your average cost, your variation is still nearly 3X that $9. Spending is far less tied to inflation than it is to personal habits, choices, and weather. In my opinion.

Comment: (I think the word you were looking for is "prediction".)

Comment: Even if such a formula existed, it would actually be many different formulas for different kinds of expenditures.  There's no way you can factor in something like an expected rise in the price of fuel without having a model that tracks fuel prices as a whole (not just your own expenditures), and even if you factor that in, there's no reason to suppose it would help in deciding how much other expenses (like food) will change.  Basically you're asking for a way to forecast the entire economy, which no one has yet found a reliable way to do.

Comment: There isn't really one formula you can use. You can develop a model for a specific expense and use that model to predict future spending, but your prediction will only be as accurate as your model. The inputs to the model depend on how you live your life. For your fuel costs, we have no way of knowing how likely it is that you'll take a 1,000 mile roadtrip next month or whether your car will be at the mechanic all month. You, as the person who both knows your spending best and has the ability to control future spending, are the best person to forecast your future expenses.

Comment: Is the fuel used for a vehicle?  Or for heating a home?  If for a vehicle:  Do you plan to use the same vehicle in the next three months as is the previous three months?  How do you expect your city (stop-and-go) driving distance to change?  How do you expect you highway driving distance to change?  Will you drive faster or slower on the highway?  Are fuel prices likely to be different?  If you are heating a home, how will the expected number of "heating degree days" be different in the next three months than they were in the previous three months?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a formula:

Average of past 3 months * expected increase factor = next month's predicted expense.

Repeat this for each expense, using actual past 3 months for each, and your guesstimate for the expected increase for each.

For example, if you spent $150, $200, and $180 and your guesstimated increase factor is 1.05, then your model predicts that your next month's expenses will be about $185.

Try to get really good at guesstimating, because the formula isn't very useful without that.

Comment: Fair enough, but 1.05 offers a huge annual rate of increase. Right? The normal inflation is eclipsed by his own variation. So if the equation were just the 3 mo average it would be no less accurate. iMHO

Comment: 1.05 was just an example. It must include inflation, changes in personal use, and changes in the underlying expense itself. It could be negative, it could be positive, it could be 0. Gasoline recently has had declining prices, while healthcare has had increases. Guesstimating is hard stuff...

Comment: Exactly! Now, Imagine having to add this factor for each and every item of regular spending. Will he add a factor for weather on his heating or ac bills? Or would an average monthly number based on last 12 months suffice?

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer - as always, it depends. If you want precision, you spend time slogging through the details. If you don't care about precision, then you just average all your expenses together and take a guess. (There is no magic formula. As you said, spending is far less tied to inflation than it is to personal habits, choices, and weather. )

Comment: My point, and obviously, I'm have trouble articulating it (side note, I am married, 21 years now, and every so often, I'll say "english fails me" to my wife. She still can't read my mind, go figure), your calculations for anything in life, can only be as accurate as your least accurate sub-component. If you are estimating your drive time to California from Boston,  knowing the distance to the nearest foot is silly. +/- 10 miles is fine, as the traffic is the biggest unknown. Either way, I am your upvote, as your answer is sound.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer - I agree. I was not as clear as I wanted to be. My point is that it isn't possible to come up with a simple over-arching formula for predicting future expenses this way. As you point out there are far too many unknowns that you must guesstimate, making the overall results less than meaningful.